# How to find which app owns a modal window?

Tags: macos, security, cocoa

I have a modal window popping up randomly with the message:

> **Insecure update error!**
>
> For security reasons, you need to code sign your application or sign
>   your updates with a DSA key. See Sparkle's documentation for more
>   information.

I know Sparkle is an autoupdate framework used by Mac applications so how can I find which application is failing on the update process?

Comment: Do you want to know the app or do you want to know how to let your app get the app?

Comment: I want to know which app is trying to update itself.

Comment: Why the cocoa tag?

Comment: This is on OSX, the app is likely written in Cocoa. Plus, Cocoa developers might know a trick to find this out.

Comment: Also see [Insecure update error!  DSA key. Sparkle](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7477406) from Apple communities. It appears to happen with Apple Mail, and I doubt Apple is using it. Its probably a plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can scan which of your installed apps are using the Sparkle framework by doing this in the Terminal:

```
find /Applications -path '*Autoupdate.app/Contents/Info.plist' -exec echo {} \; -exec grep -A1 CFBundleShortVersionString '{}' \; | grep -v CFBundleShortVersionString
```

and then update the ones that are using old Sparkle versions (and therefore are affected by this issue) - or uninstall them if their authors haven't made the necessary updates yet.

Comment: How does this answer the OP question? He is asking  how to find which app owns a dialog window. Also your conclusion is not correct, because this error is not caused by an old Sparkle version, but rather by an app using an insecure url (i.e. non https://) to fetch the app. See [this](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/82710/Restore-Sparkle-framework-workaround-to-).

Comment: @fferri You’re answering to the title. I’m answering to the real question, `how can I find which application is failing on the update process`, and it solved the issue.

Comment: I beg to disagree. Your solution (which in my opinion is still very useful and very related to the question) finds a list of apps using Sparkle. It gives no indication of which app is responsible of this error message.

Comment: `find /Applications -name Sparkle.framework -print` is cleaner

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html), which is one of the Developer Tools.

Use the **Start inspection follows point** toolbar button, then click on the titlebar of the dialog with the error message, and under **Advanced -> Parent** you can find information about who is owning that dialog.

Tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.

(in my case, that dialog was coming from mySIMBLHelper)